# How many PhD programs does the average STEM applicant apply to in Europe (Germany, Austria, Switzerland)?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, reference-request, europe

I was wondering if there are data on the number of applications that people make to PhD programs in Europe (Ger, At, CH). My guess is that it depends on the area/field, in particular I am looking for data from engineering/chemistry.

Comment: Reading the title, this does not seem like a good question to me (it's more of a poll). SE is a place for clear questions and answers. But maybe there is some statistical data that answer your question, I don't know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a polling question.

Comment: The OP is probably interested in the average number of applications.

Comment: I edited the question to try to make it a better fit by removing the poll like nature. Feel free to continue to edit and improve it.

Comment: I figured without a mention of the country it must be the US, apparently I guessed wrong. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: I suspect comprehensive and reliable data about this will be very difficult to find, given that unstructured doctorates are especially widespread in the mentioned countries. Thus, on the one hand, "applying" is often a matter of keeping in touch with unviersity staff and following up from previous projects (thus possibly making *1* a very frequent (though not necessarily total average) number), and on the other hand, the whole process of getting into such a "program" often works in a way that based on research-related talks with professors and other staff, the semi-final decision is made ...

Comment: ... to let the student start their doctorate, and only as late as that the first "formal" data about the application process (that could thus be "counted" when finding data for statistics on applications) might start appearing anywhere.